# If $f$ is differentiable on an interval and intersects each of its tangent lines just once, then $f$ is either convex or concave on that interval

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

In Chapter 11 *Appendix* of Spivak's *Calculus*, there is an author-provided proof (denoted as "Theorem 4") for the following statement:

> If $f$ is differentiable on an interval and intersects each of its tangent lines just once, then $f$ is either convex or concave on that interval.

For my convenience, I am going to post a picture of this proof (if it is necessary to write up the proof in LaTeX, I can do that, as well):

[image: Theorem 4]

My issue with this proof arises from my understanding of the final sentence: *Thus, either $f$ is convex or $f$ is concave*.

Here is the definition of **convex**:

> A function $f$ is convex on an interval if for $a,x,$ and $b$ in the interval with $a \lt x \lt b$ we have \begin{align} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \lt \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \end{align}

For arguments sake, suppose $\forall t \in [0,1]$ we have that $g(t) \gt 0$. This implies that:

$$\forall t \in [0,1]: \frac{f(y_t)-f(x_t)}{y_t-x_t} \lt \frac{f(z_t)-f(x_t)}{z_t-x_t} \quad (\dagger_1)$$

Given that $x_t \lt y_t \lt z_t$, it is not hard to spot the resemblance between $(\dagger_1)$ and the definition of convexity.

However, it is not immediately apparent to me why Spivak created these parameterized functions $x_t,y_t,$ and  $z_t$.

To show that $(\dagger_1)$ implies the definition of convexity, it seems to me that I should fix $x_t$ and $z_t$ at a particular value, while varying $y_t$ **not** by changing $t$ (because that would change $x_t$ and $z_t$) but, rather, by continuously redefining $y_t$ by changing $b_1$. For example, let's use $t=1$. In this case, $\dagger_1$ becomes:

$$\frac{f(b_1)-f(a_1)}{b_1-a_1} \lt \frac{f(c_1)-f(b_1)}{c_1-b_1} \quad (\dagger_2)$$

Because everything we have proven is for arbitrary $b_1$ (so long as $a_1 \lt b_1 \lt c_1$), I believe it is a correct interpretation of $(\dagger_2)$ to say:

$$\forall b \text{ where } a_1 \lt b \lt c_1: \frac{f(b)-f(a_1)}{b-a_1} \lt \frac{f(c_1)-f(b)}{c_1-b}$$

But $a_1$ and $c_1$ are also arbitrary (so long as $a_1 \lt b_1 \lt c_1$ is satisfied) so I feel like it is valid to say:

$$\forall a,b,c \text{ where } a \lt b \lt c: \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \lt \frac{f(c)-f(b)}{c-b}$$, which is the definition of convexity.

If this is all correct, then **why does Spivak even go through the trouble of introducing the parameterized functions**?

It seems as though I only needed a single value of $t$ to solve this problem (in the above case, I chose $t=1$). At no point did I use all of the values afforded to me in the interval $[0,1]$. Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

My initial inquiry amounts to suggesting the following approach (which I will lay out and then demonstrate why  it is incorrect):

---

*Suggested (but ultimately incorrect) Approach*

Scrap the parameterized functions and simply make the following claim:

For any $a,b,c \in I$ where $a \lt b \lt c$, we have that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} - \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \neq 0 \quad (*)$. If equality held, then we would have the contradiction outlined in part 1 of Spivak's proof.

However, this conclusion will *not* lead us to the definition of convexity (or concavity), which states:

> $f$ is convex on $I$ if for all $a \lt b \lt c \in I$ we have \begin{align}\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \lt \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \end{align} or in the case of concavity: \begin{align} \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \gt \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \end{align}

The reason $(*)$ does not imply either of those definitions is clear: consider the set of numbers $a_1 \lt b_1 \lt c_1 \in I$ and $a_2 \lt b_2 \lt c_2 \in I$. By $(\dagger_1)$ we might have $\frac{f(b_1)-f(a_1)}{b_1-a_1} \gt \frac{f(c_1)- f(a_1)}{c_1-a_1} $ and $\frac{f(b_2)-f(a_2)}{b_2-a_2} \lt \frac{f(c_2)-f(a_2)}{c_2-a_2}$. In which case, clearly we could never achieve our desired definitions. $(*)$ simply does not equip us with enough information to make any useful inference.

---

**So what does Spivak do?**

He introduces the parameterized functions **in combination with** a very important function $g$, which will remedy our earlier argument's deficits.

In particular, after providing the parameterized functions, Spivak asks us to consider the function:

$$g(t)=\frac{f(y_t)-f(x_t)}{y_t-x_t}-\frac{f(z_t)-f(x_t)}{z_t-x_t}$$

The important feature of this function (which is omitted by Spivak) is that it is *continuous*. You can verify this fairly quickly by noting that:

1. all of the parameterized functions, by themselves, are continuous
2. $f$ is continuous
3. Given the range\image of the parameterized functions, the compositions of $f$ with parameterized functions are continuous
4. given that for any $t \in [0,1]$, $x_t \neq y_t \neq z_t$, we know that their difference will never be equal to $0$.
5. Because the division of functions that are continuous where the denominator never equals $0$ is, itself, a continuous function, we can now conclude that $g$ is continuous.

This is important because the *Intermediate Value Theorem* (IVT) is now in play. Combining this with the fact that $g(t) \neq 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$, we can guarantee that the sign of $g$ never changes (otherwise, by the IVT, we would have a $t^*$ such that $g(t^*)=0$). This is why Spivak is correct in asserting, "So either $g(t) \gt 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ or $g(t) \lt 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$".

To understand why this final statement implies that $f$ is convex (or concave) on $I$, consider the following argument:

---

By definition, we call $f$ *convex* on an interval $I$ if for any $a,x,b \in I$ with $a \lt x \lt b$, the following is true:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \lt \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \quad (\dagger_1)$$

As a reminder, here is what Spivak's proof says (when assuming, WLG, that $g(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$...$(\color{red}{!})$ there is a special point that needs to be made about this, which I will include at the bottom):

> Suppose that $a_0 \lt b_0 \lt c_0$ and $a_1 \lt b_1 \lt c_1$ are all points in interval $I$. Consider the functions:
> \begin{align} &x_t=(1-t)a_0+ta_1\\&y_t=(1-t)b_0+tb_1 \quad 0 \leq t \leq1\\&z_t=(1-t)c_0+tc_1\end{align} Then $x_0=a_0$, $x_1=a_1$, and all other $x_t$ for $t \in (0,1)$ are in $(a_0,a_1)$. We have analgous statements for $y_t$ and $z_t$. Note, further that $x_t \lt y_t \lt z_t$. **Take as a given that** for all $t \in [0,1]$: \begin{align}\frac{f(y_t)-f(x_t)}{y_t-x_t}  \lt \frac{f(z_t)-f(x_t)}{z_t-x_t} \quad (\dagger_2)\end{align} Then we can conclude that $f$ is convex on the interval $I$.

---

Although I omitted some other information, Spivak, in effect, states that $(\dagger_2)$ *implies* $(\dagger_1)$.

All of the statements made above are true for any $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,c_0,c_1 \in I$, so long as the inequalities of $a_0 \lt b_0 \lt c_0$ and $a_1 \lt b_1 \lt c_1$ are upheld. Therefore, we can let $a_0=a_1$, $c_0=c_1$, and simply let $a_0=a_1 \lt b_0 \lt b_1 \lt c_1 = c_0$.

Because $a_0 = a_1$ and $c_0=c_1$, we see that $x_t$ and $z_t$ are constants. Specifically, for any $t \in [0,1]: x_t=a_0$ and $z_t = c_0$. Next, note that the function $y_t$ defines a straight line connecting $b_0$ to $b_1$. Therefore $y_t$ restricted to $[0,1]$ touches all points in the interval $[b_0,b_1]$. Thus, we can update $(\dagger_2)$ to the following statement:

For all $t \in [0,1]$:

$$\frac{f(y_t)-f(a_0)}{y_t-a_0} \lt \frac{f(c_0)-f(a_0)}{c_0-a_0}$$

...and because the function $y_t$ defines a straight line connecting $b_0$ to $b_1$, we can update this further as:

For all $b \in [b_0,b_1] \subset (a_0,c_0)$:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a_0)}{b-a_0} \lt \frac{f(c_0)-f(a_0)}{c_0-a_0} \quad (\dagger_3)$$

However, the $b_0$ and $b_1$ that we chose to define $y_t$ were arbitrary (so long as they satisfied $a_0 \lt b_0 \lt b_1 \lt c_0$). As such, $(\dagger_3)$ actually generalizes to **any** closed interval subset of $(a_0,c_0)$. It is easy to show ([How to translate "any open interval" and "any closed interval" from English to math symbols.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357978/how-to-translate-any-open-interval-and-any-closed-interval-from-english-to-m)) that this implies:

For all $b \in (a_0,c_0)$:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a_0)}{b-a_0} \lt \frac{f(c_0)-f(a_0)}{c_0-a_0} \quad (\dagger_4)$$

However, $a_0$ and $c_0$ were arbitrarily chosen in our definitions of $x_t$ and $z_t$. Therefore we can generalize to the following statement:

For all $a \lt b \lt c \in I$:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \lt \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \quad (\dagger_5)$$

i.e. $f$ is convex on $I$.

---

$(\color{red}{!})$ When I made the claim that "WLG, assume $g(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$", there is an additional lemma that needs to be provided in order for the above argument to work.

When I assume $g(t) \lt 0$, note that $g$ is defined relative to the specific parameterized functions $x_t,y_t,$ and $z_t$, which, themselves, are defined relative to the specific $a_0,a_1$, the specific $b_0,b_1$, and the specific $c_0,c_1$, respectively. So, really, we should think of $g$ as $g_{x,y,z}$ and $x,y,z$ as $x_{a_0,a_1}$, $y_{b_0,b_1}$, and $z_{c_0,c_1}$. With this, our "WLG" statement becomes:

> WLG, assume $g_{x,y,z}(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$.

In the above argument (i.e. the "**Why does $(\dagger_2)$ imply $(\dagger_1)$**" section), notice that we first generalized our *specific* $b_0$ and $b_1$ values to any $b_0$ and $b_1$ value in $(a_0,c_0)$. Subsequently, we generalized our *specific* $a_0$ and $c_0$ values to any $a_0$ and $c_0$ value in $I$. Throughout these generalization procedures, how can we be sure that our initial assumption of "$g_{x,y,z}(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$" *carries over* to these generalizations, which effectively use *new* $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,c_0,c_1$ values?

For the generalization related to $b_0,b_1$, suppose we have new values $d_0,d_1$ such that $a_0=a_1 \lt d_0 \lt d_1 \lt c_0=c_1$. Note that this means $y_t$ is no longer the same function as it was with $b_0,b_1$. We will call this new parameterized function $w_t$. Further, suppose $[d_0,d_1] \cap [b_0,b_1] = \emptyset$. We will show that the claim:

> $g_{x,w,z}(t) \gt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$, **given** that $g_{x,y,z}(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$

will lead to a contradiction. Note that if $[d_0,d_1] \cap [b_0,b_1] \neq \emptyset$, we would immediately have a contradiction.

Consider two new values $f_0,f_1$ such that $a_0=a_1 \lt f_0 \lt f_1 \lt c_0=c_1$. Impose the following condition: $[f_0,f_1] \cap [d_0,d_1] \neq \emptyset$ and $[f_0,f_1] \cap [b_0,b_1] \neq \emptyset$. Further, let $v_t$ be the parameterized function related to $f_0$ and $f_1$. We know that for any $t \in [0,1]$:$g_{x,v,z}(t) \gt 0$ or for any $t \in [0,1]$: $g_{x,v,z}(t) \lt 0$. However, because the intersections of $[f_0,f_1]$ with $[b_0,b_1]$ and $[d_0,d_1]$ are non-empty, we immediately see that our requirements cannot be satisfied. Therefore, we must have that $g_{x,w,z}(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$.

We can therefore state that **if $g_{x,y,z}(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$**, we must necessarily have $g_{x,q,z}(t) \lt 0$ for any $t \in [0,1]$, where the $q$ subscript refers to an arbitrary parameterized function $q_t=(1-t)j_0+tj_1$ such that $[j_0,j_1] \subset (a_0,c_0)$.

A very similar argument will work for when we generalize $a_0$ and $c_0$.