# How to translate "any open interval" and "any closed interval" from English to math symbols.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In my intro to real analysis book, I came up with the following lemma (which is easy to prove) to help with an exercise.

> For any open interval $K$, if any closed interval $S$ that is a subset of $K$ has the property that for any $x \in S$:$\varphi(x)$, then for any $x\in K$, we must have $\varphi(x) \quad(\dagger)$

For the proof, consider any $x \in K$. Now, consider the set $\{x\}$. This set is a closed set. Therefore, by assumption $\varphi(x)$.

**Question**: Could someone help me translate the English of $(\dagger)$ into the appropriate math notation?

How does one encode "$K$ is any open interval" and "$S$ is any closed interval"? Are these strictly topological notions that require new notation? Or is there a clever way that uses basic quantifiers and inequalities?

For example, does the following syntax work?

> $\forall K \Bigg[\bigg(\Big[\exists a,b \in \mathbb R: \forall x (a \lt x \lt b \rightarrow x \in K) \Big] \text { and } \Big[\forall S\color{blue}{\big(}\color{red}{(}\exists a,b \in K: \forall x (a \leq x \leq b \rightarrow x \in S)\color{red}{)}\rightarrow \forall x \in S: \varphi (x)\color{blue}{\big)}\Big]\bigg) \rightarrow \forall x \in K: \varphi (x) \Bigg] $

**Edit**:

I think it may be necessary to add a further specification to each of the conjuncts in the overarching antecedent.

For example, in the statement $\exists a,b \in \mathbb R: \forall x (a \lt x \lt b \rightarrow x \in K)$, I have not ensured that $K=\{x \in \mathbb R : a \lt x \lt b\}$. Rather, I have only ensured that $\{x \in \mathbb R : a \lt x \lt b\} \subseteq K$. To guarantee equality, I would have to add the condition that $\forall x ( x \leq a \text{ or } x \geq b \rightarrow x \notin K)$.

A similar extra condition would have to be stipulated for $S$.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you trying to do some kind of proof verification using a computer?

Comment: @JosephCamacho no, nothing like that. I find that my ability to form arguments is improved if I can convert my English thoughts into the appropriate symbolic representations (sometimes, parts of the proofs *jump out* for me when I have them written in the technical notation rather than plain English)

Comment: I think a much better idea is to try to get over this thing where you understand "mathematical" notation better than plain English...

Comment: "$K$ is an open interval" _is_ mathematical notation

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What are your thoughts on this: If someone were to ask me "Prove that $K$ is an open interval", and I did not know what this meant in terms of quantifiers, or an English phrase that captures the essence of quantifiers, I would shrug and say, "I do not know how to prove this". However, if someone provided me with this:

Comment: $K \text{ is an open interval } \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \exists a,b \in \mathbb R\Bigg[ \Big(\forall x: a \lt x \lt b \rightarrow x\in K\Big) \land \Big(\forall x : x \leq a \lor x \geq b \rightarrow x \notin K \Big) \Bigg]$ then I'd say, "Okay, I know what I need to prove". This is why I find value in understanding what these phrases mean in terms of quantifiers.

Comment: @S.Cramer Your point seems to be that if someone asks you a question about open intervals and you don't know what an open interval is you're in trouble, but if they **give** you thedefinition of "open interval" you're ok. That's true - I don't see what it has to do with the english-versus-symbols issue. If someone gives you the definition in words that should help just as much. To repeat with a little emphasis: if as you say you have a hard time reading mathematical English that's a problem that you need to fix.

Comment: @S.Cramer "in terms of quantifiers" has nothing to do with it. Because the English phrase $for every $x$" **is** a quantifier.

Comment: (typo: "for every $x$".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to make a few notes:

- Bear in mind that stuff like $K, S$ are just names. You don't need to give coordinates/bounds for your intervals necessarily, unless you want to specifically reference those bounds. It's the same with any set: unless you need to reference particular features or elements, don't overcomplicate details.
- You can assume, as needed, any definitions in statements like these. Your translation need not somehow include a definition of what it means to be an open interval. If need be, you can literally just say what $K,S,$ etc. are, if doing so is cumbersome symbolically. There generally isn't issue with this. Mathematical language is in part about communication, after all.

  - (After all, going to an extreme, we shouldn't have to define basic notions like set inclusion, set membership, or even basic notations like "what is a real number" for stuff like this to be meaningful. Those are handled elsewhere; make sufficient assumptions on what the reader knows so that we can concisely yet precisely communicate what we need to.)

---

So, to translate

> For any open interval $K$, if any closed interval $S$ that is a subset of $K$ has the property that for any $x \in S$:$\varphi(x)$, then for any $x\in K$, we must have $\varphi(x) \quad(\dagger)$

I would simply go with

$$\begin{align*}
&(\forall K \subseteq \Bbb R \text{ an open interval})(\forall S \subseteq K \text{ a closed interval})(\forall x \in S)(\varphi(x)) \\
&\implies (\forall x \in K)(\varphi(x))
\end{align*}$$

Broken down a bit:

- Let $K \subseteq \Bbb R$ be some open interval...
- ...where for any subset $S \subseteq K$ where $S$ is a closed interval...
- ...and each $x \in S$ has property $\varphi(x)$.
- Then we say that property $\varphi(x)$ holds for all $x \in K$.

If you want to avoid the writing things as text, you could then introduce notation representing $K,S$ as intervals formally: $K = (k,\ell)$ and $S = [s,t]$ below:

$$(\forall (k,\ell) \subseteq \Bbb R)(\forall [s,t] \subseteq (k,\ell) )(\forall x \in [s,t])(\varphi(x)) \implies (\forall x \in (k,\ell))(\varphi(x))$$

---

*(Or something to this effect anyhow, it's hard for me to parse through what you wish to translate, but I think I'm somewhere close at least.)*

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Shouldn't the closed interval be universally quantified, rather than existentially? I am saying that part of the assumption is "*All* closed subsets of a given K have the the property $\forall x \in S: \varphi(x)$."

Comment: Yeah I suppose so. Like I said, I was having some confusion translating that.

Comment: (+1) Especially for the introductory notes, which I think are far more useful for the OP's enlightenment about the issues at hand than anything else one might say.

Answer (score 1):

> $\forall K \Bigg[\bigg(\Big[\exists a,b \in \mathbb R: \forall x (a \lt x \lt b \rightarrow x \in K) \Big] \text { and } \Big[\forall S\color{blue}{\big(}\color{red}{(}\exists a,b \in K: \forall x (a \leq x \leq b \rightarrow x \in S)\color{red}{)}\rightarrow \forall x \in S: \varphi (x)\color{blue}{\big)}\Big]\bigg) \rightarrow \forall x \in K: \varphi (x) \Bigg]$

Slight reformat, altering merely punctuation and spacing:
\begin{gather}\forall K\, \Bigg[\quad\quad\quad
\bigg(\quad\exists a{,}b {\in} \mathbb R\;\forall x\;\big(a \lt x \lt b \rightarrow x \in K\big) \text { and }\\
\forall S\;\Big(\exists a{,}b {\in} K \;\forall x \;\big(a \leq x \leq b \rightarrow x \in S\big)\rightarrow \forall x {\in} S \;\varphi (x)\Big)\quad\bigg)\\
\rightarrow \forall x {\in}K\; \varphi (x) \quad\quad\Bigg]\tag0\end{gather}

> For any open interval $K$, if ***any*** closed interval $S$ that is a subset of $K$ has the property that for any $x \in S$:$\varphi(x)$, then for any $x\in K$, we must have $\varphi(x). \quad(\dagger)$

**The second “any” in your lemma $(†)$ is ambiguous; *your formalisation $(0)$ indicates that you mean it as “every”* rather than “some”.** Thus $(†)$ can be formalised as follows:

Let $P$ and $L$ be the set of open intervals and the set of closed intervals, respectively. Then
$$∀K{\in}P\;\bigg[∀S{\in}L\,\bigg(S\subseteq K→∀y{\in}S\,φ(y)\bigg)→∀x{\in}K\,φ(x)\bigg];\tag{1}$$ [equivalently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication),
$$∀K{\in}P\;∀x{\in}K\;∃S{\in}L\;∃y\;\bigg[\bigg(S\subseteq K→\Big(y{\in}S→φ(y)\Big)\bigg)→φ(x)\bigg];\tag{2}$$ [equivalently](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((K%7E5(E%7E5P))%7E5Q)%7E4((E%7E1K%7E1%7E3P)%7E2Q)),
$$∀K{\in}P\;∀x{\in}K\;∃y\;∃S{\in}L\;\bigg[\bigg(y{\in}S ∧ S\subseteq K ∧ ¬φ(y)\bigg) ∨ φ(x)\bigg],\tag3$$ i.e., “For each $x$ in each open interval $K,$ there is some $y$ and some closed interval $S$ such that either $y$ in $S$ in $K$ fails to satisfy $\varphi,$ or $\varphi(x)$ holds.”

---

**Reply to the OP's comments**

> Hmmm. I may be wrong, but something seems a little fishy. Suppose $S$ is not a subset of $K.$ Your statement then suggests that $φ(x),$ where $x$ is a member of $K,$ would need to be true. But I do not believe that is appropriate.

Remember, $S$ is a *variable* set, and my suggestions $(1),(2),(3)$ all require that you consider *only* those that are subsets of $K,$ checking whether their elements satisfy $φ.$ Non-subsets of $K$ aren't relevant.

> I just dont see how your interpretation can be reconciled with what the accepted answer (by Eevee Trainer) has provided, which as far as I can tell, echoes my syntax.

There are **two unequivalent (semantically distinct) ways** to read Eevee's suggestion $$ (\forall K{\subseteq}\Bbb R \text{ an open interval})(\forall S{\subseteq}K \text{ a closed interval})\forall x{\in}S\,\varphi(x) \implies \forall x{\in}K\,\varphi(x):$$ either as $$ (\forall K{\subseteq}\Bbb R \text{ an open interval})\bigg[(\forall S{\subseteq}K \text{ a closed interval})\forall y{\in}S\,\varphi(y) \implies \forall x{\in}K\,\varphi(x)\bigg],$$ **which [*is* equivalent to](https://www.umsu.de/trees/#((K%7E1L)%7E5P)%7E4(L%7E5(K%7E5P))) my suggestion** $$∀K{\in}P\;\bigg[∀S{\in}L\,\bigg(S\subseteq K→∀y{\in}S\,φ(y)\bigg)→∀x{\in}K\,φ(x)\bigg],\tag{1}$$ or as $$ (\forall K{\subseteq}\Bbb R \text{ an open interval})(\forall S{\subseteq}K \text{ a closed interval})\bigg[\forall y{\in}S\,\varphi(y) \implies \forall x{\in}K\,\varphi(x)\bigg],$$ **which is based on interpreting the ambiguous “any” in your lemma $(†)$ as “some” instead of “every”** (refer to the second paragraph above).

P.S. Since quantifiers are conventionally understood to apply to as small a scope as possible, technically, Eevee's suggestion is read as
$$ \bigg[(\forall J{\subseteq}\Bbb R \text{ an open interval})(\forall S{\subseteq}J \text{ a closed interval})\forall y{\in}S\,\varphi(y)\bigg] \implies \bigg[\forall x{\in}K\,\varphi(x)\bigg];$$ since this is conceivably not the intention, we insert the parentheses elsewhere.

P.P.S. Each link above contains a proof of the asserted logical equivalence.

Comment: I am trying to parse your post script. Could you please confirm that "$\forall x \varphi(x) \rightarrow \psi (y)$" should be read as "$\Big [\forall x \varphi(x) \Big] \rightarrow \psi(y)$"?

Comment: Hmmm. I may be wrong, but something seems a little fishy. Suppose $S$ is not a subset of $K$. Your statement then suggests that $\varphi(x)$, where $x$ is a member of $K$, would need to be true. But I do not believe that is appropriate.

Comment: You make the following claim:

Okay, suppose that $S\not\subseteq K.$ Then, in your original formalisation $(0),$ $$\exists a{,}b {\in} K \;\forall x \;\big(a \leq x \leq b \rightarrow x \in S\big)$$ is false, which makes $$\forall S\Big(\exists a{,}b {\in} K \;\forall x \;\big(a \leq x \leq b \rightarrow x \in S\big)\rightarrow \forall x {\in} S \;\varphi (x)\Big)$$ true (because, given any statement P, it is always the case that False${\implies}\,P);$ consequently, $φ(x)$

Comment: I am not sure I agree with the argument you have laid out. To  avoid all of these symbols, I am just going to let $\psi(S):=\exists a{,}b {\in} K \;\forall x \;\big(a \leq x \leq b \rightarrow x \in S\big)$. Then we simply have $\forall S\Big (\psi(S) \rightarrow \big[ \forall x\in S: \varphi(x)\big] \Big)$. The statement "$S \not \subseteq K$" amounts to saying that $\psi(S)$ is false. Why, then, is it the case that we must have $\varphi (x)$?

Comment: I don't want to waste too much of your time, so feel free to call it quits whenever, but consider the following argument:

Let $\psi(K):= $ $K$ is an open interval of the reals. Let $\eta_{_K}(S):=$ $S$ is a closed interval and a subset of $K$. Let $\rho(S):=\forall x \in S: \varphi(x)$.

After some additional thought, I am still **not certain** that my original syntax, written as: $\forall K \Bigg(\Big[\psi(K) \land \forall S \big(\eta_{_K}(S) \rightarrow \rho(S) \big) \Big] \rightarrow \rho(K) \Bigg)$, is incorrect.

Comment: Your proposed improvement, I believe, is to write $\forall K \Bigg(\Big[\psi(K) \land \forall S \big(\eta_{_K}(S) \land\rho(S) \big) \Big] \rightarrow \rho(K) \Bigg) \quad (*)$. I am having great difficulty understand this formula: $\forall S \big(\eta_{_K}(S) \land\rho(S) \big)$. To prove $(*)$, I would necessarily have to assume that $\forall S \big(\eta_{_K}(S) \land\rho(S) \big)$ is true. But how can I possibly assume this to be true? To assume this is true is to assume that every set in the universe is a closed subset of $K$, which is clearly nonsense. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Maybe I am oblivious...but I do not see that you changed anything. $0r$ still contains the issue that I pointed out. Hah, it's okay, though. I appreciate the effort. I just dont see how your interpretation can be reconciled with what the accepted answer (by Eevee Trainer) has provided, which as far as I can tell, echoes my syntax.

Comment: To me,  $(3r)$ needs to replace the conjunction (you used the text $\text{ and }$) with an implication...i.e. $\rightarrow$. This is what Eevee Trainer has, I believe. As written, you are saying "If $S$ is a closed set, then [it is a subset of $K$ and has the property $\forall x \in S: \varphi(x)$]"

Comment: I am very uncertain about $3r$ being correct, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: @S.Cramer I've revised the Answer. Please disregard all the above comments.

Comment: @S.Cramer For reference, [this explanation from today](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4360934/21813) parallels my last point (before the postscript) above.