# Confirmation required: Author's implicit logic behind using parameterized functions to make a universal claim

Tags: logic

There is a proof that I recently encountered, and I wanted to confirm that I am correctly understanding the argument.

Here are the relevant parts:

---

By definition, we call $f$ *convex* on an interval $I$ if for any $a,x,b \in I$ with $a \lt x \lt b$, the following is true:

$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \lt \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \quad (\dagger_1)$$

Next, the argument proceeds as follows:

> Suppose that $a_0 \lt b_0 \lt c_0$ and $a_1 \lt b_1 \lt c_1$ are all points in interval $I$. Consider the functions:
> \begin{align} &x_t=(1-t)a_0+ta_1\\&y_t=(1-t)b_0+tb_1 \quad 0 \leq t \leq1\\&z_t=(1-t)c_0+tc_1\end{align} Then $x_0=a_0$, $x_1=a_1$, and all other $x_t$ for $t \in (0,1)$ are in $(a_0,a_1)$. We have analgous statements for $y_t$ and $z_t$. Note, further that $x_t \lt y_t \lt z_t$. **Take as a given that** for all $t \in [0,1]$: \begin{align}\frac{f(y_t)-f(x_t)}{y_t-x_t}  \lt \frac{f(z_t)-f(x_t)}{z_t-x_t} \quad (\dagger_2)\end{align} Then we can conclude that $f$ is convex on the interval $I$.

---

Although I omitted some other information, the author, in effect, states that $(\dagger_2)$ *implies* $(\dagger_1)$. The only way I can see why this is justified is as follows (**if there are other interpretations, please share**):

All of the statements made above are true for any $a_0,a_1,b_0,b_1,c_0,c_1 \in I$, so long as the inequalities of $a_0 \lt b_0 \lt c_0$ and $a_1 \lt b_1 \lt c_1$ are upheld. Therefore, we can let $a_0=a_1$, $c_0=c_1$, and simply let $a_0=a_1 \lt b_0 \lt b_1 \lt c_1 = c_0$.

Because $a_0 = a_1$ and $c_0=c_1$, we see that $x_t$ and $z_t$ are constants. Specifically, for any $t \in [0,1]: x_t=a_0$ and $z_t = c_0$. Next, note that the function $y_t$ defines a straight line connecting $b_0$ to $b_1$. Therefore $y_t$ restricted to $[0,1]$ touches all points in the interval $[b_0,b_1]$. Thus, we can update $(\dagger_2)$ to the following statement:

For all $t \in [0,1]$:

$$\frac{f(y_t)-f(a_0)}{y_t-a_0} \lt \frac{f(c_0)-f(a_0)}{c_0-a_0}$$

...and because the function $y_t$ defines a straight line connecting $b_0$ to $b_1$, we can update this further as:

For all $b \in [b_0,b_1] \subset (a_0,c_0)$:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a_0)}{b-a_0} \lt \frac{f(c_0)-f(a_0)}{c_0-a_0} \quad (\dagger_3)$$

However, the $b_0$ and $b_1$ that we chose to define $y_t$ were arbitrary (so long as they satisfied $a_0 \lt b_0 \lt b_1 \lt c_0$). As such, $(\dagger_3)$ actually generalizes to **any** closed interval subset of $(a_0,c_0)$. It is easy to show ([How to translate "any open interval" and "any closed interval" from English to math symbols.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4357978/how-to-translate-any-open-interval-and-any-closed-interval-from-english-to-m)) that this implies:

For all $b \in (a_0,c_0)$:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a_0)}{b-a_0} \lt \frac{f(c_0)-f(a_0)}{c_0-a_0} \quad (\dagger_4)$$

However, $a_0$ and $c_0$ were arbitrarily chosen in our definitions of $x_t$ and $z_t$. Therefore we can generalize to the following statement:

For all $a \lt b \lt c \in I$:

$$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \lt \frac{f(c)-f(a)}{c-a} \quad (\dagger_5)$$

i.e. $f$ is convex on $I$.

I think my approach is correct...but the fact that this was left as an implicit relationship makes me think that there is, perhaps, a much easier path that links $\dagger_1$ to $\dagger_2$.

Cheers~