# Negation of statement - Propositional logic

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I am slightly confused over the negation of propositions. In particular, I have to negate the 2 following propositions:

(i) $\forall x \in X, x \in Y \implies X \subseteq Y.$

(ii) $\forall x,y \in X, (x,y) \in X^2 \implies (y,x) \in X^2.$

My attempt is as follows:

The statement (i) means that if all elements in $X$ are in $Y$, then $X$ is a subset of $Y$. Its negation is:

(i) $\exists x \in X, x \in Y \land   X \not \subseteq Y.$

This is a statement of a relation being symmetric. If it's not symmetric, then there is some pair $(x,y)$ for which this fails.

(ii) $\exists x,y \in X, (x,y) \in X^2 \land (y,x) \not \in X^2.$

Could someone verify my attempt? Thank you.

Comment: The first means if Y contains an element of X, then it contains X.

Comment: Read (i) like this: If for every/all/any $x$ that belongs to $X$, $x$ also belongs to $Y$ then $X\subseteq Y$. Now read your negated statement. There is at least one $x$ in $X$ which is also in $Y$ **and** $X \nsubseteq Y$. What does that even mean? How is that the negation of (i)?

Comment: Thanks a lot William! I can understand it now! So it would be $\forall x \in X, x \in Y \land X \not \subseteq Y$. Thank you !

Comment: $P \implies Q \equiv \neg P \vee Q$ so $\exists x \in X$ that is not in $Y$ or $X \subseteq Y$ so negation should be, $\forall x \in X, x \in Y$ *and* $X \nsubseteq Y$.

Comment: Right! (I finished writing my comment after you'd already commented).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful with parentheses when quantifiers are involved. Strictly speaking, your statements should actually be

(i) $\big(\forall x \in X, y \in Y\big) \implies (X \subseteq Y)$

(ii) $\forall x, y \in X, \big( (x, y) \in X^2 \implies (y, x) \in X^2\big)$

So your negation of the (ii) is correct. You followed the proper order. The quantifier $\forall x, y \in X$ is **outside** the parentheses and so you negated it first. Then, you negated the expression $(x, y) \in X^2 \implies (y, x) \in X^2$ **inside** the parentheses as required.

However, your negation of (i) is wrong. Notice that $\implies$ is **outside** all the parentheses in this case. So you have to negate that first. Hence, the actual negation of (i) is:
$$
\big(\forall x \in X, y \in Y\big) \land (X \not\subseteq Y)
$$

Comment: That was really helpful! Thank you!

Comment: @Balkys glad to be of help